# Spring Cloud Data Flow in AKS using ACR with a managed identity : metadata

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, azure-container-registry, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

We have a Spring Cloud Data Flow server (SCDF) deployed in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).
We defined a user managed identity assigned to this AKS.
This identity has the AcrPull role on an Azure Container Registry (ACR) that doesn't have an admin user.

In the SCDF [documentation](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/applications/application-metadata/#container-registry-support), only the authorization type 'basicauth' is described :

```
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].registry-host=tzolovazureregistry.azurecr.io
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].authorization-type=basicauth
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].user=[your Azure registry username]
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].secret=[your Azure registry access password]
```

But as we use an user managed identity, we don't have a user/secret.

We tried the authentication type 'anonymous' without success.

How to configure the SCDF to be authorized to get the metadata of the container application ?

Answer (score 0):

It works by defining a service principal and using its application ID and secret.

```
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].registry-host=myazureacr.azurecr.io
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].authorization-type=basicauth
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].user=[service principal application ID]
- spring.cloud.dataflow.container.registry-configurations[myazurecr].secret=[service principal secret]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are always using the private registry you can configure a secret directly in AKS and reference it using:
spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.imagePullSecret
or

spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.imagePullSecrets